# GNU Parallel Two or More Commands in Parallel in Sequence

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

First and foremost, I'm a huge fan of GNU parallel. I'd like to speed up a daily chore comprised of downloading, unzipping, and processing some files in parallel. Currently I do this in a sequence where the unzipping and processing don't start until the download in complete. For example, in a shell script I would run these two lines:

```
cat /home/data/daily_dload.txt | parallel -j5 "wget -O /home/data/tmp/{1} -r https://server1.hogan.hulk.warrior

ls -1 /home/data/tmp | parallel -j5 "gunzip /home/data/tmp/{1}"
```

Is there a way to get the unzipping going as soon as a file is finished downloading? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `&&` operator:

```
cat /home/data/daily_dload.txt | parallel -j5 "wget -O /home/data/tmp/{1} -r https://server1.hogan.hulk.warrior/{1} \
&& \
gunzip /home/data/tmp/{1}"
```

Comment: do you need to surround the && operator in \ and  \ ?

Comment: No. It's just that I wanted to be explicit in showing two commands separated by a `&&`. The `\`s are there to skip lines in order to have the earlier.